# How to migrate local OS users and groups to LDAP (debian wheezy)

Tags: ldap, migration, debian

How to migrate local OS users and groups to LDAP (debian wheezy)
In my system, there are about 2,500 users.
How to make the migration to LDAP (fusiondirectory)

Answer (score 2):

**Migrating Users from /etc/passwd to LDAP**

```
apt-get install migrationtools
cd /usr/share/migrationtools/
```

then edit the conf file named **migrate_common.ph** with:

```
$DEFAULT_MAIL_DOMAIN = "yourdomain.com";
$DEFAULT_BASE = "dc=yourdomain,dc=com";
```

Now export your local grp and passwd files:

**NOTE:** If you use a different shadow file, edit migrate_passwd.pl to point to that modified shadow file.

```
./migrate_group.pl /etc/group ~/group.ldif
./migrate_passwd.pl /etc/passwd ~/passwd.ldif
```

**NOW:**  After you have run the migrate commands, you will want to edit the new ldif files and remove the entries you don’t need in the database (any daemons, root, maybe another couple users, etc..)

Time to create the OU’s. To do this, make a file in your home dir named people_group.ldif containing (of course modifying the dc’s):

```
 dn: ou=People, dc=yourdomain, dc=com
 ou: People
 objectclass: organizationalUnit
 dn: ou=Group, dc=yourdomain, dc=com  
 ou: Group  
 objectclass: organizationalUnit
```

**NOTE:** The above file gave me problems. May want to do two separate files, a *people.ldif* and *group.ldif*

Now to import into the db:

```
ldapadd -x -W -D "cn=admin,dc=yourdomain,dc=com" -f ~/people_group.ldif
ldapadd -x -W -D "cn=admin,dc=yourdomain,dc=com" -f ~/group.ldif
ldapadd -x -W -D "cn=admin,dc=yourdomain,dc=com" -f ~/passwd.ldif
```

It will ask you for your admin password for the db each time. then you are good to go…Hopefully…

Comment: export PAER5LIB=/usr/share/migrationtools/ before running the scripts